# error creating Membership : Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: membership_id

Tags: civimember

Civicrm : When creating a new membership I get this error message. : Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: membership_id Membership is not created, but the contribution is created. I have double-checked the membership types and pricing and see nothing out of the ordinary. The list of members is displayed normally with new contribution.
Registration for events and activities is hassle-free.
-Joomla 3.10.6, Civicrm: 5.43.2, php 7.4.28

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. errors in the creation of contribution. confusion between pricing and membership in civimember

Answer (score 1):

If you have "Admin only" membership types, this stops the ability to create contribution and membership record. Change the membership types to "Public" as a workaround. Using Pricesets negates the need to have "Admin only" membership types.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on a Wordpress site recently and opening the Membership Type and resaving it in the UI (without changing any settings) seemed to resolve it. I'm guessing it was something related to a past upgrade process that left a wrinkle somehow and resaving ironed it out.